# unable to resume activity - illegal state exception for android 4.0

Tags: android, android-intent, android-cursoradapter, illegalstateexception, android-cursor

In my app , I am facing issue in android 4.0 .THIS ISSUE IS NOT FACED ON ANDROID 2.3 following are the steps which causes issue - 
1. I have one main activity TaskManagerActivity (activity 1)
2. Then I move to another activity ReminderModificationActivity (activity 2)
3. Make some DB changes and return back to Activity 1
4.Then exit app by pressing back button. I get following error when i try to open the app again -

```
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {ray.kaushik.simple.task.manager/ray.kaushik.simple.task.manager.ReminderModificationActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@412a9708
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2575)
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: trying to requery an already closed cursor  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@412a9708
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591):     at android.app.Activity.performRestart(Activity.java:5051)
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5074)
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2565)
11-06 13:25:37.075: E/AndroidRuntime(6591):     ... 10 more
```

I think my app is trying to load Activity 2 which I dont want.

Code on bac button press on activity 1 -

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            if(isBackPressed){
                moveTaskToBack(true);
                mDBHelper.close();
                finish();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please press back again to exit application", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                isBackPressed = true;
            }

            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); 
    }
```

Can sumone plz help me out..?? Please be elaborate as I am new to android development.Thanks

Comment: why do you need movetasktoback?

Comment: i think thts a piece of redundant code..I am anyways finishing it off.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the issue. My Activity 2 was getting called even though it should have been Activity 1 the launching activity that should have been called.

I added android:noHistory = true on my manifest file and bingo its working..

Thanks for the help guys..!!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are gathering your Database cursor again in onResume method of your Activity 1.

Comment: I dont have any onresume method on activity 1. Can you please elaborate with some code.i am new to android so cudnt figure out most of d stuff..!! :(

Comment: Sure, this should get you some idea: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html about application lifecycle. When you're leaving the app your DB cursor is destroyed (it should be), and then when you're resuming your app you shoud populate it again.

Answer (score 0):

You're failing in onResume of some app.  You're calling finish in response to the back button, which will end this activity and resume the previous one.  Then crashing because you're querying a closed cursor in onResume of that activity. If you don't want to go back to that other activity, you should call finish on it after launching this activity.

Comment: I added onresume for activity 1 and added Log message but none of my onREsume fn getting called for activity 1 or 2.